# Unite similar methods (using generic?)

Tags: c#, generics

Given sample is demonstration of my struggling. I need to unite `FillBaseClass` and `FillBaseClass` methods (DRY) and don't know how. What are my options?. Is it somehow possible?

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(int a, int b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }

    public void DoSomeCalculation()
    {
        C = A - B;
    }

    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(int a, int b, int propertyOdDerivedClass) : base(a, b)
    {
        PropertyOfDerivedClass = propertyOdDerivedClass;
    }
    public int PropertyOfDerivedClass { get; set; }
}


public class OtherClass
{
    public void FillBaseClass(List<StorageFile> files, List<BaseClass> listToFill)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var item = new BaseClass(file.Name.Count(), file.Path.Count());// just sample..
            item.DoSomeCalculation();
            listToFill.Add(item);
        }
    }
  //Join these 2 methods together?
    public void FillDerivedClass(List<StorageFile> files, List<DerivedClass> listToFill, int someOtherInt)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var item = new DerivedClass(file.Name.Count(), file.Path.Count(),someOtherInt);// just sample..
            item.DoSomeCalculation();
            listToFill.Add(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did not get what your intention to identify Base vs Derived object creation? However, for your questions you can identity the base vs derived object creation based on `someOtherInt` parameter. Make it nullable. If it's null then create the `BaseClass` instance otherwise `DerivedClass` instance.

Comment: I think you should consider the [Rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(computer_programming))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just make the third parameter as `Nullable<int>` and based on its value create the correct instance?

So I will simply do something like below:

```
public void FillClass(List<StorageFile> files, List<BaseClass> listToFill, int? someOtherInt = null)
{
    BaseClass item;
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (someOtherInt.HasValue)
            item = new DerivedClass(file.Name.Count(), file.Path.Count(),someOtherInt.Value);
        else
            item = new BaseClass(file.Name.Count(), file.Path.Count());

        item.DoSomeCalculation();
        listToFill.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Notice that the third parameter has a default value `null` so you can call `FillClass` without supplying it.

Comment: You are adding an instance of DerivedClass in a list for Base Class? Contravariance.

Comment: I'm simply using Subtyping polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

You will be taking the consumer to accept any entity which is either the base class or a child of base class. Note that if you have 2 such entities, like the one in your question, you will need two instances of OtherClass, one having base class provider and another as derived class.

Pseudo code below:-

```
    public class ClassHandler<T> where T : BaseClass, new()
{
    public void FillEntity(List<StorageFile> files, List<T> listToFill)
    {
        T obj = null;
        files.ForEach(file =>
        {
            switch (typeof(T).Name)
            {
                case "BaseClass":
                    obj = new BaseClass(file.BaseProp) as T;
                    listToFill.Add(obj);
                    break;
                case "DerievedClass":
                    obj = new DerievedClass(file.BaseProp, file.DerievedProp) as T;
                    listToFill.Add(obj);
                    break;
            };
        });           
    }
}
```

*Consumer code*

```
var base = new OtherClass<BaseClass>();
var derieved = new OtherClass<DerievedClass>();
List<StorageFile> files = GetFilesFromSomewhere();
List<DerievedClass> derievedClasses = new ...
List<BaseClass> baseClasses = new ...
var listOfDerieved = base.FillEntity(files, derievedClasses);
var listOfBase = derieved.FillEntity(files,baseClasses );
```

Comment: And how do you create a new instance of T in FillEntity to add it to the List<T>?

Comment: Use a switch on typeof(t) then call appropriate constructor. Here the generic method will only be able to call the entity method. Or can use default(t) to get a Def instance

Comment: Each such class will take in the StorageFile object as sole constructor parameter and thn construct itself based on its properties

Comment: AFAIK there is no switch for typeof(T) in c#.

Comment: @Andy, why the issue with typeof(T) ? Ofcourse it will give you a type, but then you have to either do a ToString to get fully qualified name or do a ".Name" to get just the class name..

Comment: i think Dictionary<Type, Func<StorageFile, T>> would be a better solution instead of string compare on typeof(T).Name. e. g. 
Dictionary<Type, Func<StorageFile, T>> factory = new Dictionary<Type, Func<StorageFile, T>>(); 

And then: 
factory.Add(typeof(BaseClass), file => { return new BaseClass(file) as T;});
factory.Add(typeof(DerivedClass), file => { return new DerivedClass(file) as T;});

Comment: Dictionary to store a Func, this is a new thought to me, looks interesting though will try it out